# USB became write-protected after trying to install Windows on BOOTCAMP

Tags: bootcamp, usb, bootable-disk

I tried to install windows using BootCamp, and it formatted my usb and loaded windows files and gave me an error that not enough space available, so I changed my mind and wanted to use my pen drive for other works, but bootcamp made it write-protected not able to format it or edit it, Tried using disk Utility and many more...

[image: Error I am getting in Disk Utility]

Answer (score 1):

Partition or Erase the disk rather than the partition: in the Disk Utility sidebar, choose ‘Kingston DataTr…’ rather than ‘WinInstall’ and try your operation again.

Comment: No not working Already tried that as well

Comment: I’m getting the error. Unmounting disc, creating the partition map, couldn’t open device, operation failed if I do it as you said

Comment: Maybe take out the hard drive then put it in and then repeat his suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal

1. diskutil list to find the device /dev/diskXX (/dev/disk3, etc)
2. diskutil eject /dev/disk3
3. sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=10m

Be patient it may take a while.  This should write random data to the Flash drive, effectively wiping it.  You should then be able to remove it and re-insert and re-format it however you wish.

Some Flash drives have a write protect hardware switch, make sure that is not engaged.

Reboot try this again if it fails.  It should not fail. Unless the disk is bad or it's one of those fake USB drives that claim to have more storage than it really does.  Scammers selling fake USB drives, etc.